# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing after droplet reboot

Tags: node.js, angular, digital-ocean

Hosted on Digital Ocean with a droplet. The app was working fine, but decided to resize droplet back to original plan since I did not need the upgrade. Turned droplet off to perform the resize, then turned the droplet back on.

Once droplet was turned back on, the app no longer allows me to login. I take a look at the browser console and it reads:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://api.mydomain.com/api/admin/login.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status
> code: 502.

Could someone help direct me with what commands to run from SSH to enable this properly?